# How to make height:100% of a fly-out submenu?

Tags: javascript, height, navbar, submenu

If anyone can help me I'd really appreciate it!

I've searched through all of the height:100% questions, and none seem to help my situation. How can I make the height of the sub-menu fly-out bar go all the way to the top and bottom of the screen? Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alh3168/hE6Sv/.

I already have the .second menu div set to height 100%:

```
div.menu ul.second li a {
width: 150px;
bottom: auto;
min-height: 100%;
background-color: #B2CC7F;
color: #00293E;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 7px 10px 0 0;
text-align: left;
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
background: #000; 
background-color:rgba(0,180,180,0.3);
padding-left:20px;
font-family: Neou-Bold; 
src: url('Neou-Bold.otf'); 
font-size:10px;
letter-spacing:1.6px ;
}
```

Comment: Something like this:http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/JPtRb/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the body, HTML and any parent divs have the height set as 100% also.

Comment: I'd take a look at the fiddle but I can't edit it on my tablet